# Is there a way to select two individual UV islands, and grouping/parenting them to each-other?

Tags: uv

Is there a way to group UV islands together? That way you can overlap identical islands and when you pack them, blender doesn't just take them apart?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I do that with Vertex snap enabled in UV editor, and then just move 1 of the UV islands over to the other identical one, it should snap right into place!

Comment: Indeed, but then when you pack the islands it separates those and puts them next to each other uniformly.